# How can get total price between two column?

Tags: php, mysql

Example:
    $from = 30 and $to = 33. 
Now I want to get total price between $from and $to.

Here is my code.

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) as totalPrice FROM price WHERE price BETWEEN '$from' and '$to'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['totalPrice'];
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post your code which you've tried. We're here to help you but we won't write the complete code for you!

Comment: You need to be more specific, and provide what the outcome would be.

Comment: Select total from table where to = 33 and from = 30

Comment: @pamblam dont get the logic with OR.. well OP can better explain

Comment: Please check my code  again and suggest me...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  price as total FROM yourtable WHERE from = 30 AND to = 33
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(`price`) as total FROM `table` where from = 30 AND `to` = 33
```

..MAYBE CHANGE AND TO OR, DEPENDING ON WHAT YOU WANT.

Comment: No need to use sum AND it will be AND not OR

Comment: it's given NULL result when I am trying to apply your code in database. I need to total price between 30 and 33

Comment: "Between 30 and 33" is not specific.  Also i forgot to put "from" column in backticks.

Comment: But idk how to do backticks on my phone